# Image highlight (hover state) on active section while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have these icons above each section on my page (the largish circular icons, please see example: http://pftest.fhero.net) with colored hover states... what I would really love to do is have them change to the active hover states as the user scrolls to each section (preferably with a simple fade transition) - much like the effect of highlighting the active links/section in the navigation.

There are many tutorials, plugins and questions on this site and so forth for highlighting active sections in a navigation however, but doesn't seem to be much that I can find relating to applying the effect to another div or image on the page...

I'm definitely not any kind of jQuery expert but I'm wondering if one of the myriad of scripts/plugins available which  are typically used for highlighting active states in navigation could simply be adapted to this scenario somehow to achieve the same effect? Perhaps even the one I am currently using on my page?

Here is the script I'm using for highlighting the active section in the navigation on my page:

```
/* Scroll Navigation highlight */

$("#work-section1").parent().addClass('active');
var main = main = $('#mainmenu ul');

$('.scroll').click(function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

var full_url = this.href,
    parts = full_url.split('#'),
    trgt = parts[1],
    target_offset = $('#'+trgt).offset(),
    target_top = target_offset.top;

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 500);

/* Remove active class on any li when an anchor is clicked */

main.children().removeClass();

/* Add active class to clicked anchor's parent li */

$(this).parent().addClass('active');

});

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
   if($("#work-section").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()){
    $("#work-section1").parent().addClass('active'); 
    $("#about-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#footer-section").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#services-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#process-section1").parent().removeClass('active');      
}
   if($("#about-section").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()) {
    $("#about-section1").parent().addClass('active'); 
    $("#work-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#footer-section1").parent().removeClass('active');  
    $("#services-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#process-section1").parent().removeClass('active');                
} 
   if($("#services-section").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()){
    $("#services-section1").parent().addClass('active'); 
    $("#about-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#work-section1").parent().removeClass('active');
    $("#footer-section1").parent().removeClass('active');
    $("#process-section1").parent().removeClass('active');       
}
   if($("#process-section").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()){
    $("#process-section1").parent().addClass('active'); 
    $("#about-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#work-section1").parent().removeClass('active');
    $("#footer-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#services-section1").parent().removeClass('active');          
} 
   if($("#footer-section").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()){
    $("#footer-section1").parent().addClass('active'); 
    $("#about-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#work-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#services-section1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
    $("#process-section1").parent().removeClass('active');              
}       
});
```

and the HTML:

```
    <nav id="mainmenu" name="mainmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="scroll" id="work-section1" href="#work-section">Works</a></li>           
        <li><a class="scroll" id="about-section1" href="#about-section">About</a></li>            
        <li><a class="scroll" id="services-section1" href="#services-section">Services</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" id="process-section1" href="#process-section">Process</a></li>                
        <li><a class="scroll" id="footer-section1" href="#footer-section">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>                
    </nav> 

<section id="about-section" data-anchor-offset="90"> 
<section id="work-section" data-anchor-offset="90"> 
...ect...
```

Could this somehow be adapted to accomplish the effect I am looking for? Or any other/better methods, or plugins I should be looking at?

I should add that the icons use the sprites method which could make the CSS side of things a little trickier, although I would be willing to change them to non-sprite images if necessary...

Comment: What about some HTML code as well? Would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a small little function for this, that checks if a element is on screen. I set up a little JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/LHrkB/1/

Code:

```
function isElementVisible(elementToBeChecked)
{
    var TopView = $(window).scrollTop();
    var BotView = TopView + $(window).height();
    var TopElement = $(elementToBeChecked).offset().top;
    var BotElement = TopElement + $(elementToBeChecked).height();
    return ((BotElement <= BotView) && (TopElement >= TopView));
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
       isOnView = isElementVisible(".inview");
       if(isOnView){
          //What to do when element is visible
           $(".inview").css({"background":"#ccc"});
       }else{ // If not visible

       }
});
```

Ok, so i have changed the JSFiddle a bit, now it uses a fadeIn on a invisible element when it comes into view: http://jsfiddle.net/LHrkB/2/

---

Ok, i changed the JSFiddle once again. When you scroll in the results pane, and you play around with it a bit you can see the element change class as it comes on screen and also when it goes away again. I commented the JS so you can see what it does and where it does it. http://jsfiddle.net/LHrkB/4/

Comment: Your javascript appears to use some kind of inline CSS technique I am unfamiliar with - I'm just a little confused as to what I would need to put in there to change it to the active hover state classes (which are works-icon:hover, process-icon:hover ect.) for the images? Any chance I could get a working example with images instead? :) –

Comment: The CSS technique was just to do something when the element is on screen. You could also change the class of the element, so that you can style that class with the same style as you do on :hover.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm just a bit dim today but I still can't work out how to get this to apply to the class for the hover states on the images - and I don't need the elements themselves to fade in and out entirely, which is what your example seems to do. Thanks anyway....

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve, but unfortunately it's not possible to trigger pseudo-selectors like that. The common way of achieving what you describe would be to add a class selector to your CSS and toggle the class on and off for the element.

So, in your stylesheet style a class exactly as your :hover style. When the elements enters the screen, you can add that new class with jQuery using the script i poster in my answer.

Comment: Okay, so for example the style for the hover state of one of the icons: .about-icon:hover is simply {background-position: 0 0;} (it's a sprite image, so it's just shifting the image down) I would add this style to a new class, say something like .about-icon-active and put that in place of the .inview class in your example... but then what would my HTML be? At the moment it is: <div class="section-icon about-icon"</div> - do I need to have another div referring to the .about-icon-active class and set it to display: none or something?  thanks again for your continued patience...

Comment: I'm not sure how to reference the class which would contain the styling for the hover state (.about-icon-active) in the HTML without having two separate DIVs basically (which would seem to mess the layout up from my testing)

Comment: You are definitely on the right track. Ok, so the script i set up for you in the JSFiddle is listening for an element, so it can react when it's on screen, right? When the element hits the screen, you can use: addClass to give it the ".about-icon-active" class and when it goes of-screen you can use removeClass to remove the active class. That way it will look like it uses the hover state and you don't need 2 elements :)

Comment: Only problem there is I know barely even the most basic of writing my own Javascript to be able to implement addClass and removeClass functions to the example you posted - you're really doing your best not to hand feed me the answer here aren't you ;p  But okay, let me see if I can work out how to do that then... gotta learn some time I guess! plus I already have something similar going on with the navigation in my JS so that should hopefully help me a bit in figuring it out too anyway.

Comment: I'll edit my answer in a few minutes, i'll try to work out a JSFiddle that gives you the answer but also explains why.

Comment: Yeees, got it all working! http://pftest.fhero.net/activeicon   Thanks man, you're awesome. Now I just need to add the fade function and it'll be super sexy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Veritas87 (who is super awesome), managed to get it all working with the following code:

```
function isElementVisible(elementToBeChecked)
{
    var TopView = $(window).scrollTop();
    var BotView = TopView + $(window).height();
    var TopElement = $(elementToBeChecked).offset().top;
    var BotElement = TopElement + $(elementToBeChecked).height();
    return ((BotElement <= BotView) && (TopElement >= TopView));
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
       isOnView = isElementVisible(".about-icon");                 
       if(isOnView){
          //What to do when element is visible
           $('.about-icon').addClass('about-icon-active');

       }else{ // If not visible
           $('.about-icon').removeClass('about-icon-active');      
       }
       isOnView = isElementVisible(".works-icon");                 
       if(isOnView){
          //What to do when element is visible
           $('.works-icon').addClass('works-icon-active');

       }else{ // If not visible
           $('.works-icon').removeClass('works-icon-active');      
       }
       isOnView = isElementVisible(".services-icon");                  
       if(isOnView){
          //What to do when element is visible
           $('.services-icon').addClass('services-icon-active');

       }else{ // If not visible
           $('.services-icon').removeClass('services-icon-active');        
       }
       isOnView = isElementVisible(".process-icon");                   
       if(isOnView){
          //What to do when element is visible
           $('.process-icon').addClass('process-icon-active');

       }else{ // If not visible
           $('.process-icon').removeClass('process-icon-active');      
       }                           
});
```

with the "...icon-active" classes of course containing the style for the icon hover states.